# R, correlation coefficient only for different type of variables

Tags: r, dataframe

Working with a  data frame similar to below and I want to find out the correlations of variables.

With R, I can do like:

```
library(PerformanceAnalytics)

month <- c("2017-01","2017-02","2017-03","2017-04","2017-05","2017-06","2017-07","2017-08","2017-09","2017-10","2017-11","2017-12")
Spending_1 <- c(66.5,66.5,38.5,49.5,66.5,66.5,38.5,49.5,32.5,32.5,32.5,32.5)
Spending_2 <- c(35,25,25,25,39,36,36,48,48,48,39,39)
Shipping_mall_1 <- c(17,50,42,51,76,17,65,57,54,32,51,81)
Shipping_mall_2 <- c(66,51,90,67,68,45,23,48,37,33,45,96)
df <- data.frame(month, Spending_1, Spending_2, Shipping_mall_1, Shipping_mall_2)

chart.Correlation(df[2:5])
```

It produces a chart showing 1-to-1 relationship.

[image]

Actually I don’t need the correlations between the same group of variables, for example no need to calculate Spending_1 to Spending_2 (-0.37), and Shipping_mall_1 to Shipping_mall_2 (0.22). I only want to see:

. Spending_1 to Shipping_mall_1

. Spending_1 to Shipping_mall_2

. Spending_2 to Shipping_mall_1

. Spending_2 to Shipping_mall_2

Because the original data frame is very wide, so I wish to ignore the correlations among the variables in the same group/type. (not necessarily with library(PerformanceAnalytics), other libraries also can do)

Thank you.

Comment: Do you have a code to define the groups?

Comment: @ANG, thank you for the comment. No, I don't have.